invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe8 0x6d 0x65
i have an application (NextJS/NestJS) connected with psql database. There's a form that user fills which works fine until i type a char like "é" in input and send the form to server, psql says invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe8 0x6d 0x65 . My server / client encodings are UTF-8. This problem is gone when i restart the server but comes back after sending successfully multiple forms that contains letter 'é'. So it comes randomly without any specific trigger from our end.
I tried to insert into database using nestjs typeorm a string that contains special french letters like "é", it works at the beginning perfectly fine then suddenly it stops working until i restart my application, endless loop. but when problem occurs i tried to insert directly to postgres through psql CLI and it works! so i think the problem is with the application end (nestjs+typeorm)

The question would be is your client encoding actually UTF8? From your problem statement I would say no. You will need to trace from the input form through NestJS what the encoding/encodings are?

Yes, 100%. I even tried to put mock data directly from nestjs service just to eliminate the client side from the equation and still same problem. Also, when it happens i get ���� as a response of find query operated by typeorm. When i check psql database through it CLI i see all chars normally. The problem disappers when i restart the backend service so it gives me some time to insert/retrive strings that contains chars like "é" and suddenly stops working after a while.

To me that indicates the issue is with NestJs. I would file an issue here nestjs issues.

You were right! i fixed it by reverting to node:20.12 version and it worked! But still, I have to report this issue. Thanks for your assistance.

I believe this UTF+8 encodings are broken might be relevant.
